# How to access to variables of a resident backends instance from the fronted instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm thinking to use backends instances to hold shared variables as each request of fronted instances accesses to them.
I would like to know how I could implement it if it is possible.
Assuming that memcache is not enough for holding shared data in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend instances are [addressable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Addressing_Backends), which means that you can send a URLFetch request towards the backend and be assured that the request is being processed by the same instance that held the shared variables.

You can have the effect that you desired by deploying a handler/servlet to your backend instance that responded with the value of the shared in-memory variable. The front end instances could then simply access the shared variable value by parsing the response of a URLFetch request as outlined above.

Please note that the latency might be in the order of hundreds of milliseconds, so this approach is not really a drop-in replacement for memcache.